# What is the Cartesian product of this?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> I am trying to find I am trying to find the Cartesian product of $\{\emptyset,1,2\} \times \{\emptyset,\{1,\emptyset\},2\}$

what i came up with so far is

edited:
{∅, (∅,{1,∅}),(∅,2),(1,∅), (1,{1,∅}) , (1,2), (2,∅),(2,{1,∅}) , (2,2)}

but I am not sure about it since, any non empty set x set = empty

Comment: $\emptyset\times A=\emptyset$, but $(\emptyset,a)\ne \emptyset$ (in fact, the usual definition of pair has $(a,b)\ne \emptyset$ for all $a,b$).

Comment: @Gae.S. is (∅,∅) correct ?

Comment: @MustafaShama "*is $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ correct?*"  The result of the cartesian product will *contain* $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ as one of the elements, yes, but will contain many other elements as well.  More explicitly,  your currently shown attempt above (*after the second edit*) is correct with the exception of that what you wrote as your first element as $\emptyset$ should instead have been $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$.

Comment: It should be a set of exactly $9=3 \times 3$ pairs, as both sets have three elements. $\emptyset$ is not a pair so does not belong in it.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition**

Let $A,B$ be sets. Then $A \times B = \{(a,b)|a \in A, b \in B\}$.

**Example**

Let $A = \{11,22\}$ and $B = \{A, \emptyset\}$. Then,
$$
A \times B = \{(11,A),(11,\emptyset),(22,A),(22,\emptyset) \}.
$$

Can you now apply this to your problem?